# Why the return value in autoload.php of composer?

Tags: composer-php, autoloader

I am focusing on the very short, generated file `vendor/autoload.php` and its final statement:

```
return ComposerAutoloaderInitXXXX::getLoader();
```

Looking at the logic of the code, when executed from an HTTP request, I could not see the need of a return value. I have removed the `return` in the final statement, only kept

```
ComposerAutoloaderInitXXXX::getLoader();
```

and tested with a simple *"HELLO WORLD"* web application and it worked the same way.

Perhaps that in some other applications of `vendor/autoload.php` we might need a return value.

What would be an example of such an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [composer's documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading):

> Including that file will also return the autoloader instance, so you can store the return value of the include call in a variable and add more namespaces. This can be useful for autoloading classes in a test suite, for example.

```
$loader = require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->addPsr4('Acme\\Test\\', __DIR__);
```

Comment: As they say, when every thing else fails, read the documentation. That's why I tried SO first. Seriously, I feel a bit ashamed that I did not read the doc...